# Sunhokey Prusa i3 axis x, y, z?

Tags: printer-building, wiring

My Sunhokey Prusa i3 arrived with a corrupted disc. I'm awaiting a new one and finished the mechanical build via YouTube videos.

I've no clue which motor controls the X, Y, and Z, axes. I"m not even positive which axis is which. YouTube vids don't show the origin of all the wires/cables/cords they connect.

Anyone know of any CLEAR and Normal speed (or slow-able) vid/diagram that shows the electronics wiring in detail?

Answer (score 2):

X-axis is right-to-left (Carriage motor)

Y-axis is front-to-back (Base/Bed motor)

Z-axis is up-and-down (lead screws)

There are several videos on YouTube.
This [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meKht2ObOWw&list=PLEHodQXu836zPQmIkCwLAE2ze_qOxoOvY) seems good.

Answer (score 1):

This diagram would appear to show the connections to the controller board. Taken from [3D Printer: Sunhokey prusa i3 2015 review](https://hackaday.io/page/1569-3d-printer-sunhokey-prusa-i3-2015-review)

> [image: Hardware connect]

Refer to Mark's answer for what axis/component each stepper motor controls.